# Are Microsoft Azure Cognitive services available on AzureStack?

Tags: azure, service, stack

I'm planning to showcase exciting end user use-cases in AzureStack to potential customers.

This is an idea exploration. 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/directory/

I expect Microsoft Azure Cognitive services to be available on AzureStack for Enterprise use-cases.

From my initial search on AzureStack Marketplace items from Azure I could not find Cognitive Services for AzureStack. What is the roadmap to bring these services to AzureStack in the future?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-stack/azure-stack-marketplace-azure-items

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All APIs on cognitive services here: https://**azure**.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/directory/ are on Azure. In fact, you buy access keys for these APIs from **Azure portal**: https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.CognitiveServicesBingSearch-v7.